# How to display an image using webpack-2 with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-2

How do I load an image (jpg) file within a React.js project? I saved the image in `/src/images` with a filename of, `iphone-template.jpg`.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    // activate HMR for React

    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
    // and connect to the provided endpoint

    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    // bundle the client for hot reloading
    // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates

    './index.js'
    // the entry point of our app
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // the output bundle

    path: resolve(__dirname, 'docs'), // changed 'dist' to 'www'

    publicPath: '/'
    // necessary for HMR to know where to load the hot update chunks
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  // devtool: "source-map"

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    // enable HMR on the server

    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'docs'), // changed 'dist' to 'www'
    // match the output path

    publicPath: '/'
    // match the output `publicPath`
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [ 'babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },

      // the below webpack config was sourced from this,
      // https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/issues/128
      // in order to load favicon.
      {
          test: /\.jpe?g$|\.ico$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
          loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'  // <-- retain original file name
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file',
        include: './src/images'
}
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // enable HMR globally

    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
  ],
};
```

**App.js**

```
import iPhone from '../images/iphone-template.jpg';

    const App = (props) => {
      return (
        <div id="parent">
          <NavBar {...navbar} />
          {/* see scratchpad.txt for removed div. */}
          <div id="iphone">
            {/*<img src={iPhone} />*/}
            <img className="iphone-template" src={iPhone} />
          </div>
```

I'm seeing an error image like the one below.
[image: error]

Comment: Any problems with your current code?

Comment: I think this is going to be webpack-2 related if I had to take a guess.

Comment: What "this"? What problem do you have with this code?

Comment: It's not displaying the image.

Comment: Any build errors from webpack? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I would also advise against using webpack to bundle your image assets, since it would be better to let your CDN or web server handle it

Comment: It's okay, as long,as you won't try to deliver a lot of images that way

Comment: My guess based on the info here is that your image is larger than 10K and thus is using file-loader instead of url-loader. Which file-loader will return a hash for the filename for your webserver to handle, but you have to specify the correct directory. So try removing the limit in url-loader and seeing if it works. And also try checking to see what React has as the value for the src (using the developer tools) or check out the react dev tools extension for chrome

Comment: Nick the image is jpg

Comment: Got it working, it was indeed the `webpack.config.js`

Comment: What html is generated?

Comment: The same.  The problem was with the posted `webpack.config.js`

Comment: "The same" what? What html was generated?

Answer (score 0):

If it's indeed webpack 2, you'll need to use `file-loader` in all the names of your loaders, because it no longer supports just `file` or `url` to use the loaders.

Other than that, you have several of them affecting your .jpg .png .gifs, etc .. you can get rid of the duplication and just write one for them all, as all you are doing effectively is copying the files (no optimization, no hash renaming), unless you'd want copies on your root, your images and your img directories within distribution

But here is the question, how are you accessing the page to display?